# how to rename directories that are hard to type?

Tags: files, directory

How can I rename oddly named directories without typing their full names?

I've got 8 folders with very long foldernames and I only got these folders in this path /home/user/Downloads/ - Is there any command to get every {*.txt} file from all folders and move them to another directory?

Comment: This question is very hard to make sense of. Edit your question to tell us what you have. Then tell us what you want. We may be able to answer that question.

Comment: see - I got 8 folders with very long foldernames and I only got these folders in this path /home/user/Downloads/ - I wanted to ask if there is any command to get every txt file of ALL folders and move them to another directory ?!

Answer (score 5):

If I rewrote your question properly based on your comment then

```
find /home/user/Downloads -type f -name \*.txt -print0 | \
  xargs -0  -I '{}' mv '{}' nice-directory
```

will reliably do what you ask.

Comment: If you'd use `xargs -0 mv -t nice-directory`, you would save on `mv` executions.

Answer (score 1):

To rename a directory like `horrible *[name]* with$weird <characters> \\in it`, you can use wildcards. For example, if you have only one directory with `weird` in the name:

```
mv "*weird*" a-regular-named-directory
```

where the `"` are important. If this fails, you can use

```
ls --hide-control-chars
```

That will give you a listing with odd characters replaced by `?`, which is then a shell pattern upon which you can use `mv`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just:

```
mv firstCoupleLetters[tab] newDir[enter]
```

and rely on autocomplete to fill out the original directory name, renaming it to something shorter/more useful.

Answer (score 0):

[msw's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/34847/631600) using `xargs` is OK.

However, I would do

1. with `find -exec` instead of `xargs`.
2. using `mv -t target sources...` form instead of `mv source target`, so you don't need to call `mv` for each file.

```bsh
find ~/Downloads -type f -name "*.txt" -exec mv -t "/path/to/other_directory" {} +
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `globstar`:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
mv ~/Downloads/**/*.txt "/path/to/other_directory"

# Unset globstar again if you don't need it anymore:
shopt -u globstar
```